# Why Are Views not Loaded via XHR in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, url-routing

Maybe a dumb question that would've gotten answered after more digging in the docs, but what the heck.  Why aren't my components' views (templates) not being loaded via XHR ( as was the case in AngularJS apps )?  I just set up my first router that is wired in to a couple of components and some menu items in my 'master' template.  Whenever I click to navigate, the page reloads with the new view, versus being displayed flicker/reload-free via XHR as in AngularJS.

Comment: According to the [router docs](https://angular.io/guide/router) it uses [html5 push state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) (it's down near the bottom)

Comment: I'm conflicted ... I don't think this is a good question for this site but I don't want to flag it as it's not ... **bad** - since it's got no answers maybe you would consider deleting it :)

Answer (score 1):

Well that was easy.  You have to use 'routerLink=' rather than 'href=' for the route links in your template.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```